# пытаюсь написать бота с викториной для вк

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

я пытаюсь написать бота с викториной для вк и наткнулся на ошибку: при определенном значении(не знаю каком) код выдает ошибку, вот сам код

```
from random import choice
class Quiz:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.questions = []
        questions_file = open(file_path,'r')
        for line in (questions_file.readlines()):
            self.questions.append(tuple(line.split(',')))
        self.count = 0        
        
        self.n = []
        for i in range(0, len(self.questions)):
            self.n.append(i)

    def ask(self):
        n_tuple = choice(self.n)
        question, self.answer = self.questions[n_tuple]
        self.n.remove(n_tuple)
        self.questions.remove(self.questions[n_tuple])
        return question



    def qanswer(self, answer):
        if answer == self.answer:
            self.count += 1
            return True
        return False

    def right_answers(self):
        return self.count
```

я только учусь, так что, не судите строго

Comment: что пишет в ошибке?

Comment: line 15, in ask
    question, self.answer = self.questions[n_tuple]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Выход за пределы списка. Мб вам нужно делать choice от длины `self.questions`?

Comment: я пытался так сделать, но у меня вышла похожая ошибка, но возможно я неправильно что то написал

Comment: Не понятно зачем формируется список n с номерами элементов. Просто берите `question, self.answer = choice(self.questions)`